# Get an element position relative to the top of the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the top position of an element relative to the top of the viewport, not the whole document.

I tried `offset().top;` which returns the top position relative to the document, and I tried `scrollTop()` which always returns `0` regardless of the element's visibility in the viewport.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can calculate it using

```
$('#element').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()
```

**Working example**

```js
function get(){
  $('#output').html($('#element').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop());
}

get();
$(window).scroll(get);
```

```css
#element {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}

#output {
  position:fixed;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="element"></div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

Answer (score 16):

For those looking for a non-jquery solution:

```
let el = /* get your el */

let top = el.getBoundingClientRect().top + 
          el.ownerDocument.defaultView.pageYOffset
```

Comment: Thanks. I myself came here looking for jQuery equivalent of getBoundingClientRect :)