# Function to be called once div hits top of viewport window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Wondering if you could have a look at the below code.

Im wanting a function to be called once the top of the red box hits the top of the viewport on scroll.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ay5ttmLk/

```
HTML
<div class="test" style="height:100px;width:70px;">
sadfsadf
saf
sadf
saf
s
af
saf
saf
sadf
sadfsafsafsaf
</div>


<div class="test" style="height:100px;width:70px;">
sadfsadf
saf
sadf
saf
s
af
saf
saf
sadf
sadfsafsafsaf
sadfsaf
sadfsafsadf
</div>

CSS
.test {margin-top: 500px;
margin-bottom: 1000px;
background-color: red;}

JS
var el = $('.test');
el.on('scroll', function(){
if(el.scrollTop() == 0){alert("hit the top")}
});
```

Comment: Just check the element's offset from top and subtract the window's "scrollTop()": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175336/get-element-position-relative-to-top-of-the-viewport

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get element position relative to top of the viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175336/get-element-position-relative-to-top-of-the-viewport)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PrashantShirke/ay5ttmLk/7/).

I have added code to alert whenever .test div reaches at top (multiple times). If you need to call the alert/some code only once then you need to remove else part.

Below is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test').attr("attop", false);
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var windowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();


    if (windowScrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
        var currentDiv = $('.test[attop="false"]:first');
        if (currentDiv && currentDiv.length > 0) {
            if (windowScrollTop >= currentDiv.offset().top) {
                currentDiv.attr('attop', true);
                alert('reached top');
            }
        }

    } else {//this part needs to be removed to call only once
        var currentTopDivs = $('.test[attop="true"]');
        if (currentTopDivs && currentTopDivs.length > 0) {
            $.each(currentTopDivs,function(i,elem){
                if (windowScrollTop <= $(elem).offset().top) {
                    $(elem).attr('attop', false);
                }                   
            });
        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = windowScrollTop;

  });
});
```

Hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to check of top viewport (there is top of document). However, you can do a manual test to check it:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() { 
    var topViewPort = $(window).scrollTop();
    // You have 2 problems here
    // - Your el is an array with two elements. You have to specify which one you want to check or add extra condition
    // - scrollTop on the element doesn't mean anything. You need to use offset().top to get the data
    var topElement = $(".test").eq(0).offset().top; 

    // Do small check (gap length < 100?) to consider it on top.
}
```