# Fade in / out text when it enters a specific position in the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fade in / out text when the user scrolls to a specific position within the viewport. It should look like what you can see on a website from [apple](https://www.apple.com/apple-tv-plus/). They used this effect at the bottom of the page in the section that says

"New Apple Originals every month.
Always ad-free and on demand."

[Here's a video of the effect](https://sendvid.com/cnfmldxq)

I've found a snippet that does in some kind of way what I am trying but the div that is holding the text always has a height of xxvh.

Here's what I have:

```js
function isElementInViewport(element) {
 var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
 return (
  rect.top >= -160 &&
  rect.left >= 0 &&
  rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
 rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
 );
}

var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".greyline");
 
function callbackFunc() {
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (isElementInViewport(elements[i])) {
 elements[i].classList.add("blackline");
}

  else { 
   elements[i].classList.remove("blackline");
  }
 }
}
 
window.addEventListener("load", callbackFunc);
window.addEventListener("scroll", callbackFunc);
```

```css
.greyline {
  color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height:65vh;
}

.blackline {
  color: black;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.textline {
  line-height: 2em;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-bottom:2em;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="greyline">
<div class="textline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</div></div>
<div class="greyline">
<div class="textline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</div></div>
<div class="greyline">
<div class="textline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</div></div>
<div class="greyline">
<div class="textline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</div></div>
<div class="greyline">
<div class="textline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</div></div>
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jomawie/wt8eLmbd/3/)

I hope you can help me. If you need any further information let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Hope this graphic shows the effect I want to reach
[sketch of the effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKKPa.png)

Comment: Can you clearly state what you are trying to solve about the height? What should it be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get element position relative to top of the viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175336/get-element-position-relative-to-top-of-the-viewport)

Comment: The height should be defined by the text. There will be about five lines of text that fade line by line from grey to black when scrolled about 65% into the view. In the snipped that I found the height is set to 65vh, so the space between the text is too big.